# When should a chapter end and the next chapter begin?

Tags: style, formatting, editing

I writing a short story and I would like to know when I should end a chapter.

Comment: I've voted to close this question, as it is far too vague to be given any sort of answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should a chapter end?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/when-should-a-chapter-end)